# Determining the horizontal position of an object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, projectile

In my calc-physics class we were given the following question:

> A movie stuntwoman drops from a helicopter that is $30.0 m$ above the ground and moving with a constant velocity whose components are $10.0 \frac{m}{s}$ upward and $15.0 \frac{m}{s}$ horizontal and toward the south. You can ignore air resistance.
>
> What is the horizontal distance(relative to the position of the helicopter when she drops) at which the stuntwoman should have placed the foam mats that break her fall?

I figured I could simply calculate the magnitude of the components since that will give me the distance, but the answer I got was incorrect.

I'm not looking for an answer, but would appreciate any assistance you all could offer in helping me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you meant by:

"I figured I could simply calculate the magnitude of the components since that will give me the distance"

But the idea is use the kinematics equations for x and y:

$x(t)=x_{0}+v_{x0}t+1/2at^2$

and

$y(t)=y_{0}+v_{y0}t+1/2at^2$

These equations are derived from integrating the acceleration function $a(t)=-g\hat{y}=-9.8m/s^2\hat{y}$

You are given the initial horizontal and vertical position ($x_{0}=0$ and $y_{0}$) and the initial horizontal and velocities ($v_{y0}$ and $v_{x0}$)

I think I may have said too much...

Comment: Your two equations are identical in every way. Did you mean to use different letters, perhaps $y$ in the second one?

Comment: @BMS Thank you for catching that! I can't believe I did that. Thanks to fibonatic for correcting it.